# where is the colormap for rastersymbolizer in geoserver?

Tags: geoserver

I´ve been reading the user manuals and tutorials in the geoserver website and I came across the RasterSymbolizer in the SLD reference page [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-reference/rastersymbolizer.html) . There you can see images of a "ColorMap" window where you can set the color ramp for the raster, but, thing is I cannot find such thing in my geoserver...

Does anyone knows how can I find it ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao,
there is no "colormap" windows, the snippet you saw on that page are SLD portions.

Couple that link with this one:
http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/rasters.html

and this one:

and you should be able to move forward.

Basically you have to create a style (SLD) that contains a ColorMaps for the raster layer you are styling. You can do this via the Styles section in the Data settings.

Simone.

Comment: THX for the answer... I do know how to make SLD´s but I was curious about the images on the page and I thougth I was missing something